# How to handle try and rescue errors in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using try and rescue, but it's not working. When I do this,

```
iex(3)> try do
...(3)>   File.read! "junaid"
...(3)> rescue
...(3)>   error ->
...(3)>     IO.inspect error
...(3)> end
%File.Error{action: "read file", path: "junaid", reason: :enoent}
%File.Error{action: "read file", path: "junaid", reason: :enoent}
```

but when I use it with my own method such as

```
iex(2)> try do                                                     
...(2)>   EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple(%{"junaid" => "junaid"})
...(2)> rescue                                                     
...(2)>    error ->                                                
...(2)>      IO.inspect error                                      
...(2)> end
```

but it won't work and give me such error

```
[error] Task #PID<0.1075.0> started from #PID<0.1065.0> terminating
** (File.Error) could not read file "junaid": no such file or directory
    (elixir 1.11.1) lib/file.ex:354: File.read!/1
    (evercam_media 1.0.1607441172) lib/evercam_media/s3.ex:46: anonymous fn/1 in EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple/1
```

Is it possible to just bypass this error and `do_something()` in rescue? or in any other clause which says, it's an error? instead of breaking the process?

Why try and rescue don't work in such a way where it will do the work in try and if there is ANY error it will just go to the rescue and don't break the process.

UPDATE: the method, `EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple`

```
  def do_save_multiple(paths) do
    upload_file = fn {src_path, dest_path} ->
      ExAws.S3.put_object("evercam-camera-assets", dest_path, File.read!(src_path),
        acl: :public_read
      )
      |> ExAws.request!()
    end

    paths
    |> Task.async_stream(upload_file, max_concurrency: 10, timeout: :infinity)
    |> Stream.run()
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental issue with an attempt to rescue the error here: `EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple/1` seems to *spawn a task*, meaning the code does not raise any error **within this process**, which makes it meaningless to try to handle it within this process. It’s like trying to catch the flight from Paris to Vienne at Barcelona’s airport.

If you own `EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple/1`, rescue the error there. If you don’t, you might either [trap exits](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html?#link/1) in the calling process and perform whatever you want in `handle_info({:EXIT, _, _}, state)` callback, or simply spawn it unlinked via e. g. [`Kernel.spawn/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#spawn/1)

```rb
spawn(fn ->
  EvercamMedia.S3.do_save_multiple(%{"junaid" => "junaid"})
end)
```

Comment: But I actually want to catch the error and then log something in DB.

Comment: You cannot catch errors from other processes. Furthermore, you cannot get access to _anything_ from the different processes. You only can ① send/receive messages there and ② get notified when the other process exits (if and only if your process is linked to another process **and** traps exits, as I linked above.)